# Drones to fly indoors

Tags: recommendations, under-250-grams, indoors

Due to the current situation, I can't go outside to fly my drone. What's a small and easy to control nano drone I can fly indoors (no camera necessary)? It should be easy to control as I don't want to crash into anything but don't want to give up drone flying altogether.

Comment: I have a 'Micro Drone' I fly indoors - one of the most useful tips I was given is that if you are about to crash, stop the props and just let it crash. It is small and light enough that it doesn't damage itself and, with the propellers at idle, I've yet to cause damage to anything else (although I avoid flying near anything fragile, just in case.) Your mileage may vary by specific drone, however.

Comment: I don't have tons of experience with drones, being a beginner, but the Blade Inductrix is really easy to control indoors (as compared to when I exchanged it with 19,000kv motors) while not lacking in power. There's also the Tiny Whoop, basically the same think but with FPV (haven't tried it), or you could use a small all-in-one camera. The best part is that it binds to my DSM2 DX5E tx, making controlling it even easier. My only complaint would be the way the motors are cheaply attached to the prop guards making it a bit easier to break, but that was when I had just started flying.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This depends - do you want to fly FPV or LOS, angle or acro?

For the LOS angle, I absolutely love the Hubsan X4 H107C. It’s relatively cheap, flies smoothly and is really robust. There is also a version without a camera called the H107L.

If you want to fly FPV acro (or angle), the Tinyhawk, Mobula 6 and Meteor 65 (though you may need a throttle cap) are all said to be very good.

Comment: +1 for the use of a throttle limit / cap for flying indoors where space is tight. Do this in betaflight CLI, eg.... set throttle_limit_type = scale; set throttle_limit_percent = 85; save